# (Py)Qt: Spacing in QHBoxLayout shows centralwidget's background, not parent's

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qmainwindow, qlayout

Consider the following example code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget,
                             QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        cwidget = QWidget(self)
        cwidget.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: red; }")
        self.setCentralWidget(cwidget)
        self.resize(100, 100)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(cwidget)
        vbox.addWidget(QTextEdit(self))
        vbox.addWidget(BlackBar(self))

class BlackBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("* { background-color: black; color: white; }")
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.setSpacing(5)
        hbox.addWidget(QLabel(text="eggs"))
        hbox.addWidget(QLabel(text="bacon"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

It has:

- A `QMainWindow`, `QWidget` as central widget (*red*), `QVBoxLayout` as a child of the cental widget. Inside there:

  - A `QTextEdit` (just as a filler)
  - A `QWidget` (*black*), which contains a `QHBoxLayout`. Inside that:

    - Two `QLabels`

This looks like this:

[image: Qt HBoxLayout]

I'd expect the spaces between the labels to be black, because the `QHBoxLayout` is a child of `BlackBar`, but it seems `BlackBar` is just "invisible" in between and the central widget "shines through". Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36884) has now been answered with a solution that's easier than @ekhumoro's answer and works:

> I don't think this is valid. The paint code your are looking for is not drawn in the `paintEvent`. Look for `QWidgetPrivate::paintBackground` instead. For performance reasons widgets will ignore style sheets by default, but you can set the `WA_StyledBackground` attribute on the widget and it should respect style sheet backgrounds.

And indeed, doing this before setting the stylesheet does the trick:

```py
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the [Style Sheet Syntax](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html) does not mention it, it seems that the `QWidget` class is treated differently when it comes to stylesheets.

Other widgets will work fine with your example code. For example, if `QWidget` is replaced everywhere with `QFrame`, then everything works as expected.

To get stylesheet support for `QWidget` subclasses, you need to reimplement the `paintEvent` and enable it explicitly:

```
class BlackBar(QWidget):
...
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        option = QStyleOption()
        option.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(
            QStyle.PE_Widget, option, painter, self)
```

Comment: Interesting - I just looked at the Qt source, and [QWidget](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/763f4e54a818f31b4e89c99ec10924b2738f5de6:src/gui/kernel/qwidget.cpp) doesn't implement paintEvent at all. Am I missing something, or should I submit a Qt bug, so this is either changed, or the documentation is clarified?

Comment: @TheCompiler. It does seem strange, and I must admit that I haven't got a definitive answer to this. My understanding is that this only affects _subclasses_ of QWidget, but I cannot remember where I got this from.

Comment: I now submitted this as [QTBUG-36884](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36884). Let's see what they say.

Comment: The bug has now been answered to with an easier solution. I answered my own question now. Thanks anyways!